# How to connect to antpool?

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, mining-hardware, asic

So I'm using an [antminer](https://www.bitmain.com/) s3. I have been on btc guild for about a week. Today they announce they are closing. So I looked around and figured I would join antpool.

The problem is when I changed all my pool config, my antminer won't start. It turns on and the fans spin very slowly.

When I was on [btc guild](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BTC_Guild) the miner ran right away. I'm not sure what the problem is. My miner stats say this section contains no values yet.

I input everything the way it showed me on [antpools](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/AntPool) website. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: Did you check that the URL is correct? Did you try contacting their support people?

Comment: directions I followed this morning. Unplug your computer from all internet sources. Plug in an ethernet cable from the AntMiner to your computer. Navigate to Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Centre -> Change Adapter Settings. Right click on your ethernet adapter -> Properties. Click on "Internet Protocol Version 4" and click properties. Select "Use the following IP address" and enter the following: IP Address: 192.168.1.1, Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0, Default Gateway: 192.168.1.99. Plug in an ethernet cable from the AntMiner to you router. Restart the configuration instructions as above.

Comment: The I went to work. The miner was not working. After 3 hours I checked antpool and found that the miner started working. It was very random that it started 3 hours later. After I did what you read up there I could not log on to the internet at all. I just got home and changed my protocol back to what it was. The miner is still hashing and I can go online, however I can not go to the miner config. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I made a good tutorial on how to setup the antminer or any bitcoin miner to antpool using the gui. Here is the link to the video:  Hopefully   it helps!

How to setup Antminer S9, or any antminers GUI to Antpool set mining pools in under 8 minutes for 2018!

https://youtu.be/o8op00b7_RM